# Center an image and a text in a div

Tags: html, css

I would like some help for this code. I'm trying to center all the content that is to say images, texts and tables. When I try to center the images with the display : block and margin-left, margin-right: auto . The images go completely right and I don't know why.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.section {
  flex: 1;
  /*grow*/
}

table.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  /*breakpoint*/
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <table class="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1460/1460537.svg" width="15%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>COTON 100% BIOLOGIQUE</h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/131/131131.svg" width="15%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>MADE IN FRANCE</h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1086/1086223.svg" width="15%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>IMPRESSION FRANCAISE</h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use  `align-items` instead of `text-align`

Comment: I suggest that you stay away from using `<table>` for positioning/designing elements. `<table>` is mostly used for displaying data only

Comment: Why not use `flex` for that?

Comment: Ok thank you and to center the elements I should put "align-items" for every elements ?

Comment: Flex ? sorry I'm learning so I'm not familair with all the attributes

Comment: Do you really need `display: flex`? Are all those css just for the goal of centering the contents?

Comment: Yes I put it in css because I thought it was the only way I can center my content.

Answer (score 4):

I just go through your code and found that you are using separate `<table>` for each `<tr>`. Where you are only using `class="center"` for only first `<table>`. Either give class="center" to each `<table>` (if your really need, not required in this case). Here is the simplified code.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.section {
  flex: 1;
  /*grow*/
}

table.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  /*breakpoint*/
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <table class="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1460/1460537.svg" width="15%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>COTON 100% BIOLOGIQUE</h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/131/131131.svg" width="15%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>MADE IN FRANCE</h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1086/1086223.svg" width="15%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>IMPRESSION FRANCAISE</h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but when it on full page the block are under one another like in a responsive mode. I would like that it stays in one line in a desktop screen.

Comment: @Krystel_T Please include that in the question body, as that is a critical info, so that it is clear for everybody

Comment: OK I will do it

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to center the content, this **css** would do:

```
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <table class="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1460/1460537.svg" width="15%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>COTON 100% BIOLOGIQUE</h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/131/131131.svg" width="15%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>MADE IN FRANCE</h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1086/1086223.svg" width="15%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>IMPRESSION FRANCAISE</h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Same code, but without using `<table>`:

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1460/1460537.svg" width="15%">
    <h3>COTON 100% BIOLOGIQUE</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/131/131131.svg" width="15%">
    <h3>MADE IN FRANCE</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1086/1086223.svg" width="15%">
    <h3>IMPRESSION FRANCAISE</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against using tables for a layout like this. I would do it with `flex-box` and it would look something like this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.container .section {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  /* breakpoint */
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1460/1460537.svg" width="15%" />
    <h3>Coton 100% biologique</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/131/131131.svg" width="15%" />
    <h3>Made in France</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1086/1086223.svg" width="15%" />
    <h3>Impression Francaise</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this css it will work

```
.section > table{width:100%;text-align:center}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `transform` property

```css
.center {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">

    <table class="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1460/1460537.svg" width="15%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>COTON 100% BIOLOGIQUE</h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <table class="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/131/131131.svg" width="15%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>MADE IN FRANCE</h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <table class="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1086/1086223.svg" width="15%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>IMPRESSION FRANCAISE</h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one table with multiple `tbody` and give `media query` css for desktop view display inline

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.section {
  flex: 1;
  /*grow*/
}

table.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 991px) {
  table tbody {
    display:table-cell;
    padding: 10px 25px;
  }
  table tbody td img {
    width:75px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  /*breakpoint*/
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <table class="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1460/1460537.svg" width="15%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>COTON 100% BIOLOGIQUE</h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/131/131131.svg" width="15%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>MADE IN FRANCE</h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1086/1086223.svg" width="15%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>IMPRESSION FRANCAISE</h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.center {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <table class="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1460/1460537.svg" width="15%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>COTON 100% BIOLOGIQUE</h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
          <td><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/131/131131.svg" width="15%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>MADE IN FRANCE</h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1086/1086223.svg" width="15%"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3>IMPRESSION FRANCAISE</h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.center {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center
}
```

Comment: or you can add <table class="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">